# In Wildfly, MDB listening to external ActiveMQ gets a null JMSMessageId

Tags: jboss, jms, wildfly, activemq-artemis

I am testing the connectivity of Wildfly16 / JBoss 7.2 with ActiveMQ Artemis 2.7.

I have written a simple MDB, and it can consume messages from the remote ActiveMQ Artemis server.

I get correctly the payload (text message) and the CorrelationId, but the received MessageId is null! This looks weird and is very annoying as I want to implement request/reply.

- To enable the access from Wildfly to the external ActiveMQ Artemis server, I followed the steps indicated in [31.3. Configuring the Artemis Resource Adapter to Connect to Red Hat JBoss AMQ 7](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html/configuring_messaging/resource_adapters#using_jboss_amq_for_remote_jms_communication). It worked.
- I have created a simple Java client that is able to send/consume/browse the queues directly. When I consume a message with this client, I get the MessageId, the CorrelationId and all the stuff I expect.
- The issue appears with a Message Driven Bean on Wildfly 16, 17 and on JBoss 7.2 (I have tried each).
- The Jar of the MDB that I deploy on Wildfly has no dependency (6Kb)

Below the code of the MDB

```java
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty;
import javax.ejb.MessageDriven;

import javax.jms.*;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.ResourceAdapter;

@ResourceAdapter("activemq-ra-remote")
@MessageDriven(name = "JmsTestMDB", activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationLookup", propertyValue = "testReqQueue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge")})
public class WildflyMdb implements MessageListener {
  private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(WildflyMdb.class.toString());

  public void onMessage(Message rcvMessage) {
    TextMessage txtMessage = null;
    try {
      if (rcvMessage instanceof TextMessage) {
    txtMessage = (TextMessage) rcvMessage;
       LOGGER.info("Received Message from queue: MessageId=" + rcvMessage.getJMSMessageID() + 
                   ", CorrelationId=" + rcvMessage.getJMSCorrelationID() +
                   ", Text='" + txtMessage.getText() + "'");

       LOGGER.info("rcvMessage (toString): " + rcvMessage.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
       LOGGER.severe("EXCEPTION:" + e.getMessage());
    }
 }
```

When I send following message with my Java client :

- MessageId: ID:DEVTEMP-PC-49242-1561392550500-1:1:1:1:1
- CorrelationId: CID:20190624180910
- Text Message: 'This is my test message'

I get the following log from the MDB in Wildfly:

```
16:23:29,694 INFO  [class com.fluide.mdb.WildflyMdb] (Thread-360 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)) Received Message from queue: MessageId=null, CorrelationId=CID:20190624180910, Text='This is my test message'
16:23:29,695 INFO  [class com.fluide.mdb.WildflyMdb] (Thread-360 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)) rcvMessage (toString): ActiveMQMessage[null]:PERSISTENT/ClientMessageImpl[messageID=946860, durable=true, address=testReqQueue,userID=null,properties=TypedProperties[__AMQ_CID=ID:DEVTEMP-PC-49242-1561392550500-0:1,_AMQ_GROUP_SEQUENCE=0,__HDR_BROKER_IN_TIME=1561392550749,_AMQ_ROUTING_TYPE=1,__HDR_ARRIVAL=0,__HDR_REPLY_TO=[0000 0011 6401 000D 7465 7374 5265 7370 5175 6575 65),__HDR_COMMAND_ID=5,JMSCorrelationID=CID:20190624180910,__HDR_PRODUCER_ID=[0000 0039 7B01 0025 4944 3A44 4556 5445 4D50 2D50 432D 3439 3234 322D 3135  ... 31 3339 3235 3530 3530 302D 313A 3100 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000 01),__HDR_MESSAGE_ID=[0000 004C 6E00 017B 0100 2549 443A 4445 5654 454D 502D 5043 2D34 3932 3432  ...  0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000),__HDR_DROPPABLE=false]]
```

As you can see, the `MessageId` returns as **null** which doesn't look right.
Any ideas?

Comment: I understand that the behavior you're observing isn't expected, but I don't understand why you actually need the message ID in the first place. I'm not aware of any request/reply pattern where the message ID is necessary. Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Also, how is the message being sent (e.g. what client library is being used)? It looks like maybe you're using an OpenWire client to send the message. Is that correct?

Comment: Hi Justin, Thanks for your reply! So the reason behind using JMSMessageID is that it is what is used by the Oracle SOA JMS connectors: It records the JMSMessageID returned when producing the message. In the response, it reads the JMSCorrelationID and correlates it to the JMSMessageID of the request.  And we want to migrate our services from Weblogic/Oracle AQ to Wildfly/ActiveMQ.

Comment: I am using `activemq-all-5.12.0.jar` in my java client. The initial context factory is `org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory` and I am looking up for `ConnectionFactory`

Comment: I forgot: I tested also `JMSReplyTo`, and it returns also `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're sending the message with a standalone Java client using the OpenWire protocol from `activemq-all-5.12.0.jar` and receiving the message with an MDB on Wildfly/EAP using the Artemis core protocol I believe you're hitting [this bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-2390) in ActiveMQ Artemis which causes messages sent and received with different protocols to have null a message ID. A pull-request has been sent already so the issue should be fixed for 2.10.0.

If you don't want to wait for 2.10.0 to be released then you can work-around the issue by using the Artemis core JMS client implementation from your standalone Java application. Just drop in the Artemis client jar (from the <ARTEMIS_HOME>/lib/client directory) and change the initial context factory to `org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory`.

Comment: Thank you Justin. So what you suggest is about tweaking the client jar of the **Artemis server**: `apache-artemis-2.7.0/lib/client/artemis-jms-client-all-2.7.0.jar`? Is that correct? Anyway I try and give you a feedback.

Comment: I'm suggesting that you use the ActiveMQ Artemis JMS client in your standalone Java application rather than the ActiveMQ 5.x JMS client that you're currently using. Nothing needs to be changed on the Artemis server.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought after more thinking and I did that. It changes quite a bit the behavior: I was sending to `testReqQueue` and now it arrives in `jms.queue.testReqQueue` on the Artemis server (it added the jms.queue prefix). I am tweaking the MDB and I give you a feedback.

Comment: YES! It works! Thank you very much. That was it! So as you suggested, I used the `artemis-jms-client-all-2.7.0.jar` taken from the `<ARTEMIS_HOME>/lib/client directory` of the artemis server and replaced the `activemq-all-5.12.0.jar` that I was using in my standalone client. I also changed in my standalone client from `org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory` to `org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory` in that same standalone client, and now everybody speaks the same langage! The MDB in Wildfly gets the right info. Thanks again Justin!

Answer (score 0):

EAP 7.2 is on Artemis 2.x so you don't have to do it that way. You could use a simple well configured pooled-connection-factory at the subsystem level : http://wildscribe.github.io/WildFly/16.0/subsystem/messaging-activemq/pooled-connection-factory/index.html

Comment: Thanks @ehsavoie for your answer. But I don't understand what you mean. I thought that by following the [redhat doc](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html/configuring_messaging/resource_adapters#using_jboss_amq_for_remote_jms_communication), I was following the right steps (indeed through a pooled connection factory). I didn't do any JMS before getting this mission of migration. So it's not easy for me. If you could provide some more guidance, I'd be grateful!

Comment: https://docs.wildfly.org/17/Admin_Guide.html#Messaging_Connect_a_pooled-connection-factory_to_a_Remote_Artemis_Server is what I was referring to